# How to separate multiple messages from a single packet in a midi input thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, midi, coremidi

I'm trying to get my midi input loop to handle multiple messages being sent in a single packet by advancing the packet index by the length of the specific command. I am receiving multiple midi messages inside a single packet this is an attempt to start the loop from the next message instead of the next packet.

Instead of starting from the next message it appears to be skipping the rest of the packet contents and missing all the messages until the next packet arrives.  You can see near the bottom I have added the command length to the packetContentsIndex to try to get the loop to start over from the next message but it's not working. Can anyone see where I'm messing up?

```
- (void) midiInputThreadProc:(id)arg
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        unsigned int maxPacketLength = 0x100;
        unsigned char* data = malloc(maxPacketLength);
        UInt16 length;

        while (semaphore_wait(midiReceivedSemaphore) == KERN_SUCCESS) {
            midi_packet_buffer_next_packet_length(midiPacketBuffer, &length);
            if( length > 0) {

                length = midi_packet_buffer_read(midiPacketBuffer, data, length);
                for (unsigned int packetContentsIndex = 0; packetContentsIndex < length; packetContentsIndex++) {
                    Byte command = data[packetContentsIndex+0];

                    switch (command){
                        case MIDI_NOTEON:
                            commandLength = 3;
                            {//sending midi message to delegate in here}
                            break;
                        case MIDI_CONTROLCHANGE:
                            commandLength = 3;
                            {//sending midi message to delegate in here}
                            break;    
                        case MIDI_SYSEX:
                            commandLength = length;
                            {//sending midi message to delegate in here}
                            break;
                    }
                    packetContentsIndex += commandLength;
                 }

            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        free(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incrementing packetContentsIndex by 1 each time through the loop, and *also* incrementing by 3 for note-on and control messages.  That would cause you to increment packetContentsIndex by 4 bytes, but a note-on message is only 3 bytes long.

It might be clearer to do something like this:

```
unsigned int packetContentsIndex = 0;
while (packetContentsIndex < length) {
  Byte command = data[packetContentsIndex];  // No reason to say +0
  unsigned int commandLength = 1; // the byte we're looking at now

  switch (command) {
    case MIDI_NOTEON:
      commandLength += 2;  // 2 additional bytes after the 1 you just saw
      break;

    case MIDI_CONTROLCHANGE:
      commandLength += 2;
      break;              
  }

  packetContentsIndex += commandLength;
}
```

This is still a pretty naive way to parse MIDI, though. Just off the top of my head:

- You can't use a simple case comparison to find note-on and control-change messages, since the channel number is included in the bottom 4 bits of that byte. You'll need to mask that part off before comparing.
- Instead of proper note-off messages, you may receive note-on messages with velocity 0, which should be treated as note-offs.
- You might get other one-byte real-time messages (like MIDI clock) interspersed in the middle of any message, even simple two- or three-byte messages, but especially sysex messages.
- Once a sysex message starts, you can't guarantee that it will finish at the end of the current packet. It might span multiple packets or packet lists, it might be really large (taking seconds or minutes to transmit), and it might not even end in a proper F7 byte.